# Kitchen sink drawer blocked by p trap

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

I made a bit of a beginner's mistake and forgot to account for the sink drawer so the drawer doesn't fully close as it hits the p-trap.

No way to lift the drain pipe since it goes into a side cabinet and then into the wall.

My last resort is sawing a hole in the back of the drawer, but open to any solutions!

Is there anyway to offset the tailpiece before the p-trap so it sits deeper in the cabinet? Not sure if this is allowed by code in Ontario (Canada).[image]

Comment: That dishwasher drain hose needs to be raised up significantly. Depending on applied code, it might also need an air gap, but minimum is to attach it to the bottom of the countertop in a high loop.

Comment: It looks like you may be able to shorten some of the fittings and get the bottom of the "P" up an inch or so.  It's not clear if that's enough to clear the drawer.  If not you have two options: Shorten the drawer or cut a slot to allow it to clear.

Comment: Thanks. Good call on the drain hose, I am indeed planning to do that.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with the drawer under my gas cooktop. Actually, for a gas cooktop many people use a false-front, as you likely have here, for the top drawer, but most gas cooktops now are extremely low profile, so that the only issue is the gas supply pipe, similar to the issue here of a trap with a lower drawer.

My solution was to cut the back piece of the drawer, cut a rectangle out of the bottom of the drawer and cut some pieces to make a fence around the rectangle. You can use either wood painted white or melamine board (which is typically not wood but some sort of fiberboard/etc.  but strong enough for cabinets/drawers).

```
+------+        +----+
|      |  Trap  |    |
|      |        |    |
|      +--------+    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
|                    |
+----------+-+-------+
          Handle
```

Comment: I've seen this done in more than one vanity _by the manufacturer_ as the solution to drawers under the sink. Some of them have the cutout so deep into the drawer that it's almost 2 drawers sharing one front and pull.

Comment: I had to do this to a house with eight sinks. Used an entire 8' piece of plastic trim in 6" increments. Use a brad nailer, and watch your fingers. They were wood though. That's IKEA and metal.

Answer (score 2):

Those look like Ikea cabinets, if so, buy a different drawer. Ikea sells a 14 3/4" deep drawer. The actual dimension is 13" deep into the cabinet. Those holes in the side of your cabinet should be 11" from the front of the cabinet frame. It looks like the back of the drawer is even with those holes. If you can push the drawer in another 2" then the shorter drawer should work. I had a similar problem with my cooktop because of the gas hook up. I was going to use a false front but found that the shorter drawer fit. You might be able to use a lower profile  drawer like the ones for silverware, although a big drawer face on a low drawer might be a bit unstable. If that doesn't do it then get out the tin snips or grinder.

Comment: A shorter back panel that they sell for a lower profile drawer, attached to the big face that you have, +1, ideally not a less deep drawer. If you're lucky there's already holes in the face to accommodate the rails at that low of a setting. ... Otherwise it's grinder time.

Comment: The optional side glass panels might add some stability. With those in at least you can tighten the rails more reasonably. Might not be an option with the rails lowered though.